# Convert pdf to html with Aspose.Pdf for Cloud

Tags: c#, pdf, aspose, aspose.pdf

I'm having trouble converting a pdf to html using Aspose.Pdf-Cloud v1.0.9.

Code:

```
public byte[] ConvertPdfToHtml(byte[] doc, string fileName)
        {
            var pdfApi = new PdfApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeSID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeUrl"]);

            try
            {
                var apiResponse = pdfApi.PutConvertDocument("html", null,
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".html", doc);

                if (apiResponse != null && apiResponse.Status.Equals("Ok"))
                {
                    return apiResponse.ResponseStream;
                }

                throw new Exception("Couldn't convert pdf - " + fileName + " to HTML...");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NLogger.LogError("ConvertPdfToHtml - " + ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

It seems that regardless of what I upload (Adobe, selectPdf) I get a 400 bad request back.  Anybody have any luck getting this to work?

Aspose.Words has worked great for me for doc / docx to html so far.

Update : After logging into the account it looks like there's an error being generated behind the scenes:

Error: The method or operation is not implemented.. Method: Convert document to the format specified on-line.. Parameters: format 'html',url '',outPath 'testadobe.html'

This might be a aspose sdk issue, I'll try contacting them as the method is exposed on the sdk and does exactly what I need it to with docs, just need it to work with pdfs too.

Updated code:

```
public byte[] ConvertPdfToHtml(byte[] doc, string fileName)
        {
            var pdfApi = new PdfApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeSID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeUrl"]);
            var storageApi = new StorageApi(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeSID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AsposeUrl"]);

            try
            {
                storageApi.PutCreate(fileName, "", "", doc);

                var apiResponse = pdfApi.GetDocumentWithFormat(fileName, "html", "", "", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".html");

                if (apiResponse != null && apiResponse.Status.Equals("Ok"))
                {
                    var storageRes = storageApi.GetDownload(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".html", null, "");

                    var htmlDoc = ZipExtractor.ExtractHtmlFromZip(storageRes.ResponseStream,
                        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + ".html");

                    return htmlDoc;
                }

                throw new Exception("Couldn't convert pdf - " + fileName + " to HTML...");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NLogger.LogError("ConvertPdfToHtml - " + ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Unzip function for posterity:

```
public static byte[] ExtractHtmlFromZip(byte[] zipBytes, string fileName)
        {
            var zipStream = new MemoryStream(zipBytes);

            if(zipStream == null) throw new NullReferenceException("zipStream doesn't contain any bytes...");

            var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream);

            foreach (var zipEntry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (zipEntry.FullName == fileName)
                {
                    var fileStream = zipEntry.Open();
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                        return bytes;
                    }
                }
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Couldn't find " + fileName + " in zip archive...");
            }

            throw new Exception("Oops... looks like this should've never been reached in ExtractHtmlFromZip");
        }
```

Comment: I've never used it myself so I probably won't be much in the way of help, but may be worthwhile including how the object that is passed in as doc is constructed, any processing, and then converted to a byte array (feels obvious, but maybe not the case). Personally, I've had an issue similar and there was a processing step that corrupted a tiff file.

Comment: @Robert I actually went through all that getting the docs in there, so I can vouch for the byte stream being pure ;)  I updated my question, it looks like it might be an issue with their api sdk.

Comment: @Erik Philips, We are investigating the bad request error and let you know once it is fixed. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: @ImranRafique I edited the question.  Your comments should be directed towards RandomUs1r :)

Answer (score 1):

We have two APIs to convert PDF document to HTML.

1. [GET /v{version}/pdf/{name}](https://apireference.aspose.cloud/pdf/#!/PdfDocument/PdfDocument_GetDocument)
2. [PUT /v{version}/pdf/convert](https://apireference.aspose.cloud/pdf/#!/PdfDocument/PdfDocument_PutConvertDocument)

I recommend you to use the first one. The following cURL example will help you to understand an API.

```
curl -v "http://api.aspose.cloud/v1.1/pdf/Sample.pdf?format=html&appSID=B01A15E5-1B83-4B9A-8EB3-0F2BFA6AC766&signature=hHUw2HKmLY6tQFEevDg52uOLKak" \
-X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: multipart/form-data" \
-o Sample_out.zip
```

As you may have observed, I set the output (-o) file extension to .zip, instead of .html, the reason is that the converted file contains multiple files (.html, .css, image files), so API zipped the output files.

This cURL example used [Sample.pdf](https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.Pdf-for-Cloud/blob/master/Data/Sample.pdf) as a resource file.

P.S. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: The 2nd one returns a byte stream with the images embedded, which is more so what I'm after.  Also, I'm using the C# nuget SDK, what would be the equivalent code for using the sdk? Is there an option, or flag I can use to get the images embedded in the html similar to the Words Api PutConvert method using the sdk?

Comment: @RandomUs1r Please check [this C# example](https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.Pdf-for-Cloud/blob/master/Examples/DotNET/CSharp/Document/ConvertPdfToHTML.cs), it converts PDF file (containing images) to HTML. The example first converts PDF file to HTML then download the converted file from Cloud to a local directory. Hopefully, this example will serve your purpose as it returns a byte stream with the images embedded.

Comment: I did, & I updated my question with the new code, however this is not what I'm after.  That generates code such as > <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="document_files/style.css" /> and <div class="stl_03">
    <object data="document_files/img_02.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="stl_04" style="position:absolute; width:49.5833em; height:70.1667em;">
     <embed src="document_files/img_02.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
    </object>
   </div>